# Using jQuery mobile button to run javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using a script that reference jQuery Mobile I have the following line:

```
<a href="#" id="buttonAnswer1" data-role="button" data-inline="true" >check</a>
```

How would I add a listener for when this button is clicked and lets say call the hello() function? i.e.

```
<a href="#" id="buttonAnswer1" data-role="button" data-inline="true">check</a>

<script>
function hello(){
  console.log("hello world");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really any different then regular jQuery, that is you can use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind an event handler

For example, using .on with event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttonAnwser1', hello);
```

Or you can bind it directly

```
$('#buttonAnswer1').on('click', hello);
```

Comment: Note that the second method needs to be included in a document ready handler and/or placed in a script block that appears _after_ the element in question - many people put their script at the end of the body. Having said that, the second method would be my first choice for a static element selected by `id`.

Comment: `document ready` should not be used with jQuery Mobile and will cause issues with ajax based loading. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14236170/64262