# Calling a function when using <button> tag with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794480/using-jquery-mobile-button-to-run-javascript) for buttons in  tags, but I find that solution doesn't work using  tags. So, if I am using a script that references jQuery Mobile I have the following line:

```
<button id="buttonAnswer1" data-inline="true">Click me</button>
```

How would I add a listener for when this button is clicked and lets say call the hello() function? i.e.

```
<button id="buttonAnswer1" data-inline="true">Click me</button>

<script>
function hello(){
  console.log("hello world");
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code you were given for your other question will bind a click handler to any element type, including `<button>`. (You don't have more than one element with the same id do you?)

Answer (score 1):

Can you please refer the below code.

```
$("button#buttonAnswer1").on("click",hello);
```

Please try the above code in jsfiddle and let me know your concerns.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to select all `<button>` with data-line set to `true`?

if so, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/M9pwp/2/

html:

```
<button id="buttonAnswer1" data-inline="true">Click me</button>
```

script:

```
$("button").click(function() {
   if ($(this).attr('data-inline') == 'true')
      hello();
});

function hello()
{
     alert('hi');   
}
```

if you only want a listener for this particular button, then you can change the script to:

```
$("#buttonAnswer1").click(function() {
    hello();
});

function hello()
{
    alert('hi');   
}
```