# When linking to a page the button text (based off JSON call) isn't loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am very new to jQuery/javascript and am basing some code off this introduction to [JSON and PHP](http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP) that ended up looking like this on my pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#bigButton").button('refresh'); 
    $.get("test.php", function(data){setupPage(data)});
});

function setupPage(data){
    eval("message="+data);     
    $("#bigButton").html(message.text);
    $("#bigButton").button('refresh'); 
}
```

It works fine when I load the page directly (adds the desired text to a button), however when I link to the page it doesn't load. It seems it is a problem with the JSON code because when I hard code the value of the button (without a call to JSON) it works.

Wondering what the problem could be.

Comment: A couple of things - firstly, don't use eval - it's a huge security issue and horrible to debug. Secondly, check your browser error console, and post any errors you are getting. I imagine it's a same origin policy issue

Comment: I specifically referenced the tutorial I used to base my code off because I thought somebody might call me out on eval :) I haven't got to the point where I've working out why eval is bad yet, but I like how in the c9.io it specifically highlights the line and says 'eval is evil' so this is definitely on my plate to work out once I get this issue resolved! Are there any quick suggestions to change eval to something else? As far as errors go, I see nothing - just a blank entry.

Comment: The whole point of JSON is that it is interchangeable with JavaScript objects, and so simply assign the data to a variable myTweets: `var myTweets=+data`

Answer (score 1):

Use `pageinit` instead of `document ready`. Drop eval, which isn't the cause of your issue but it is neither necessary nor something that should be used.

```
  $(document).bind("pageinit", function() {   });
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html