# Clicking on a button link in jQuery Mobile causes pageinit to misbehave

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code on a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Appski</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="quizPage">
        <div data-role="content">   
            <button id="bigButton"></button>
        </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#bigButton").html("hello");
        $("#bigButton").button('refresh'); 

    });

    $("#bigButton").click(function() {
        window.location.replace("page2.html");
    });
</script>


</html>
```

When I load this page it works fine and displays "hello" in the button, however when I link from another jQuery Mobile page with something like the following source code, the page loads without any text appearing in the button (and the link doesn't work either):

```
<a href="page1.html" data-role="button">click me</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When linking to a page the button text (based off JSON call) isn't loading] Same issue asked by the same person. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236170/when-linking-to-a-page-the-button-text-based-off-json-call-isnt-loading)

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the ajax call made by the jquery mobile when you go back to the previous page.

So actually when you click on the button on the second page it directly load the `data-role="page"` section of the first page via an ajax call and that's the reason that you will not get the script you wrote on the first page which display `Hello` on button.

So in this case you need to insert the same script on the second page also or you can use a common header on every page if it suits you.

And do not use `$(document).ready` you should use `$(document).on('pageinit')`. See the documentation for details [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

**So here is you first page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Appski</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('pageinit',function(e){
    $("#bigButton").html("hello");
        $("#bigButton").button('refresh');         
    });
</script>  
</head> 
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="quizPage">
        <div data-role="content">   
            <button id="bigButton"></button>
        </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Second page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Appski</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).on('pageinit',function(e){
    $("#bigButton").html("hello");
        $("#bigButton").button('refresh');         
    });
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="quizPage">
        <div data-role="content">   
          <a href="main.html"  data-role="button">click me</a>
        </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

i tested this and it is working for me. You can further optimize the code of these page.

It is better that you go through the [official event docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) also.